# Deferred deep linking using HOKO

Tags: ios, deep-linking

I want to use Deferred deep linking using HOKO. The only resource I could find from the official HOKO - about differed deep linking - was this: http://support.hokolinks.com/what-is-a-deferred-deep-link/.

Also I tried to use the HOKDeferredDeeplinking class in my project by creating a new instance and calling requestDeferredDeeplink without any luck.

Finally, I did an in depth search in the internet and I couldn't find anything helpful.

Anyone can help me with this? Has anyone tried this before?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I work with [Branch.io](https://branch.io) — we offer the most comprehensive deferred deep linking platform on the market as a free service.

**Deferred deep linking** can be thought of as the *result* you get when you've fully implemented the HOKO (or Branch) platform into your app. The blog post you referenced is talking about what deferred deep linking does at a conceptual level, but it doesn't cover how to set up the all required pieces. You would want to start with the HOKO [integration guide](http://support.hokolinks.com/quickstart/ios/) and then the [deep linking](http://support.hokolinks.com/ios/ios-deeplinking/) guide.